# Variables as values into mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a a while loop until 30 and I want to get the x as value into the query. I can't run this because I cant use the x as value. How can I do this ?
I want to use the x as hour id.
Thanks

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_day`(IN `d_id` INT, IN `date` VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
      DECLARE x  INT;
      SET x = 1;
      WHILE x  <= 30 DO

INSERT INTO  `e-heal`.`scheduler` (`scheduler_id` ,`d_id` ,`hour_id` ,`date` ,`available`)
VALUES (NULL ,  '5',  x,  '2013-04-22',  '0');

                  SET  x = x + 1; 
      END WHILE;
 END
```

Comment: I would expect that to work.  If not, have you tried replacing `values(...)` with `select ...`?

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: what happened? why you delete the code?

Comment: I deleted the answer because I had an educated guess on on what the problem might be, and no one else had responded to your questiono.  However, on further research, I realized that I don't have the detailed knowledge of MySQL to adequately answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as is. You can try adding `@` in front of `x`:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `add_day`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
       PROCEDURE `add_day`(IN `d_id` INT, IN `date` VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
      DECLARE x  INT;
      SET @x = 1;
      WHILE @x  <= 30 DO
          INSERT INTO  `e-heal`.`scheduler`
              (`scheduler_id` ,`d_id` ,`hour_id` ,`date` ,`available`)
              VALUES (NULL ,  '5',  @x,  '2013-04-22',  '0');

          SET  @x = @x + 1; 
      END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But I'm wondering what you are trying to do with the two in-parameters that you never use, and that have same name as two of the columns.

Comment: @Marjecta, if he uses @x he shouldn't declare x. x and @x are different variables